# Undefined symbol using emcmake (emscripten and opencv)

Tags: opencv, cmake, emscripten, undefined-symbol

I'm trying to build a minimalist project using OpenCV in the browser.

I've compiled OpenCV on my computer.

Here is the C++ code (josef.cpp):

```
#include <iostrem>

#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>   

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{ 
    printf("Hello here\n"); 
    cv::Mat m;
    std::cout << m;
}
```

Here is the `CMakeLists.txt` :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( josef )

# Give here the directory in which we have
# the file OpenCVConfig.cmake
set(OpenCV_DIR "/usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4")
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( josef josef.cpp )
target_link_libraries( josef ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Compiling with

```
cmake .
make
```

works perfectly well and provides an executable which produces the expected result:

```
Hello here
[]
```

My problem arises when trying with emscripten.

```
emcmake cmake .
```

produces lot of warnings like that one:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVModules.cmake:393 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVConfig.cmake:126 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

Then

```
emmake make
```

fails on undefined symbols:

```
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv3Mat10deallocateEv
warning: Link with `-s LLD_REPORT_UNDEFINED` to get more information on undefined symbols
warning: To disable errors for undefined symbols use `-s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0`
```

My question is : what do I wrong ? How to tell emscripten where are the famous missing symbols (these are the file `.so` if I understood correctly) ?

Answer (score 0):

This is partially a hack solution.

- In the file `/usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVModules.cmake`, change every instances of "SHARED" by "STATIC".
- In your `cmake` file, add the line

```
file( GLOB opencv_js "/path/to/opencvjs/opencv/build_js/lib/*.a")
```

This part supposes that you compiled opencv by hand.

- then refer to my answer to [my next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61477860/cvimdecode-an-image-from-js-to-c-opencv-emscripten/61494601#61494601). (in short: use a canvas, do not use `cv::imdecode`.)