# opencv : read an image from std::string

Tags: c++, opencv, imread

The context is that I have an html/js/canvas webpage reading a jpg file furnished by the user and sending the file to a c++/wasm function. (everything in the browser)

On the c++ part I have a function like this one:

```
void readBlob(std::string textBlog)
{
   std::cout << textBlob << std::endl;
}
```

That one works well : I see in the browser console the content of the `jpg` file.

My question are :

- how to "read" this `std::string` to create an opencv image ?
- Is there any hope to succeed without recompiling the jpg support for OpenCV and then a load of third parties ?

I've tried that one :

```
  writeInFile(textBlob, "image.jpg");
  cv::Mat image = cv::imread("image.jpg")
```

where `writeInFile` is a function which writes on the disk (wasm has its own virtual filesystem).

The problem with that approach is that `cv::imread` causes "undefined symbol" when linking (I think that I compiled opencv to wasm without codecs or something).

I'm not really good at understanding the differences between char*, buffers and all that. So I'm not sure how to use `cv::imdecode` from a `std::string`.

EDIT : here is how I encode the image into `std::string`.

In the javascript part, I draw the image in a canvas and do:

```
canvas.toBlob(manageBlob, 'image/jpeg', 1)
```

where `manageBlob` is the following:

```
function manageBlob(blob)
{
const blobText = await new Response(blob).text();
Module["readBlob"](blobText);
}
```

Here `Module["readBlob"]` is the wasm "magics" to send the js string `blobText` to the c++ function whose signature is `std::string`.

Comment: how you encode an image into `std::string`?

Comment: So is that encoding to Base64, or what?

Comment: Yes, I believe this is base64. If not, you can assume that I fix the js part to create base64.

Comment: use imdecode...

Comment: After all, I think that the whole idea is bad because it is near to impossible to use "imdecode" or "imread" in wasm : it relies on many third party libraries to be compiled for wasm by hand. See there for a better approach : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61477860/cvimdecode-an-image-from-js-to-c-opencv-emscripten